Code works locally but gets positional indexers are out-of-bounds on AWS Lambda
I'm running a code to extract data from a Gsheets Sheet and loading it into a Postgres database. The code works perfectly with other sheets of the same workbook as AWS Docker and also when I run it locally on my computer. However, when I push the code via a Docker Container to AWS Lambda I always get the error "positional indexers are out-of-bounds".
Does someone has an idea where that comes from?
Here's my code (locally, on the AWS the same just as lamda_handler function)
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import gspread as gs
from datetime import datetime
from gspread_dataframe import get_as_dataframe
from upload_functions import push_df
import numpy as np

gsheets_name = "xxx"
gsheets_token = Path("xxx")

# Initialisierung des Google Sheets Clients mit der Service-Account-Credentials-Datei
gc = gs.service_account(filename=gsheets_token)

# Öffnen des spezifischen Google Sheets
sheet = gc.open(gsheets_name)

# Zugriff auf das Arbeitsblatt "xxx"
staffing_worksheet = sheet.worksheet("xxx")
staffing_df = get_as_dataframe(staffing_worksheet, evaluate_formulas=True, header=None, skiprows=95)
staffing_df = staffing_df[staffing_df[1].notna()]

# Extraktion der Spaltennamen und Datumsinformationen
columns_A_to_E = staffing_worksheet.row_values(95)[:5]
date_row = staffing_worksheet.row_values(2)
columns_dates = pd.to_datetime(date_row[6:], format='%d.%m.%Y', errors='coerce')  # Angepasstes Format
current_week, current_year = pd.Timestamp.now().isocalendar()[1], pd.Timestamp.now().isocalendar()[0]

# Filtern der Spalten basierend auf aktuellen oder zukünftigen Daten
valid_columns = [(date.isocalendar()[1] >= current_week and date.isocalendar()[0] == current_year) or date.isocalendar()[0] > current_year for date in columns_dates]
columns = columns_A_to_E + [date_row[i+6] for i, valid in enumerate(valid_columns) if valid]
staffing_df = staffing_df.iloc[:, np.r_[0:5, 6 + np.flatnonzero(valid_columns)]]
staffing_df.columns = columns

# Hinzufügen eines Timestamps
staffing_df['pulled_timestamp'] = datetime.now()

# Bereinigung und Transponierung des DataFrames für "xxx"
pivot_list_staffing = []
for index, row in staffing_df.iterrows():
    for i, valid in enumerate(valid_columns):
        if valid:
            # Sicherstellen, dass das Datum im korrekten String-Format für den Zugriff verwendet wird
            column_date = columns_dates[i].strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
            # Erstellen einer Serie für jeden gültigen Eintrag und Hinzufügen zur Pivot-Liste
            pivot_list_staffing.append(pd.Series(
                [row[dim] for dim in columns_A_to_E] + [column_date, row[column_date], row['pulled_timestamp']],
                index=list(columns_A_to_E) + ['day', 'days', 'pulled_timestamp']
            ))

pivot_df_staffing = pd.DataFrame(pivot_list_staffing)
pivot_df_staffing = pivot_df_staffing.dropna(subset=['days'])

pivot_df_staffing.columns = ['ID', 'user', 'project_name', 'project_type', 'sum', 'day', 'days', 'pulled_timestamp']
pivot_df_staffing = pivot_df_staffing.drop(columns=['sum'])

pivot_df_staffing['day'] = pd.to_datetime(pivot_df_staffing['day'], errors='coerce', dayfirst=True)

# Daten in Datenbank pushen
push_df(pivot_df_staffing, 'staffing_mc')

I've tested that "valid_columns" is not empty and "staffing_df" is not empty.
This is the error I see on CloudWatch
LAMBDA_WARNING: Unhandled exception. The most likely cause is an issue
in the function code. However, in rare cases, a Lambda runtime update 
can cause unexpected function behavior. For functions using managed 
runtimes, runtime updates can be triggered by a function change, or 
can be applied automatically. To determine if the runtime has been 
updated, check the runtime version in the INIT_START log entry. If 
this error correlates with a change in the runtime version, you may be 
able to mitigate this error by temporarily rolling back to the previous 
runtime version. For more information, see 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-update.html
[ERROR] IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/main.py", line 37, in lambda_handler
    staffing_df = staffing_df.iloc[:, np.r_[0:5, 6 + np.flatnonzero(valid_columns)]]
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1184, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1690, in _getitem_tuple
    tup = self._validate_tuple_indexer(tup)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 966, in _validate_tuple_indexer
    self._validate_key(k, i)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1612, in _validate_key
    raise IndexError("positional indexers are out-of-bounds")


No code "works perfectly", especially code that contains no error checking. You're making a ton of assumptions about the shape and content of your input data. Consider adding bounds and field validation in the code itself (not hand verifying one file or another) to catch problematic input that you don't expect.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Did you solve your error?
